# Adding milliseconds to my Javascript stopwatch

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a script for a Stopwatch using HTML and Javascript. I have it working with hours minutes and seconds. I also have functions to stop-start the timer, stop the timer and clear the timer.

Can anyone help me add milliseconds to the stopwatch script?

Here is my code so far:

```js
var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0],
    start = document.getElementById('start'),
    stop = document.getElementById('stop'),
    clear = document.getElementById('clear'),
    seconds = 0, minutes = 0, hours = 0,
    t;

function add() {
    seconds++;
    if (seconds >= 60) {
        seconds = 0;
        minutes++;
        if (minutes >= 60) {
            minutes = 0;
            hours++;
        }
    }
    
    h1.textContent = (hours ? (hours > 9 ? hours : "0" + hours) : "00") + ":" + (minutes ? (minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes) : "00") + ":" + (seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds);

    timer();
}
function timer() {
    t = setTimeout(add, 1000);
}
timer();


/* Start button */
start.onclick = timer;

/* Stop button */
stop.onclick = function() {
    clearTimeout(t);
}

/* Clear button */
clear.onclick = function() {
    h1.textContent = "00:00:00";
    seconds = 0; minutes = 0; hours = 0;
}
```

```html
<h1><time>00:00:00</time></h1>
<button id="start">start</button>
<button id="stop">stop</button>
<button id="clear">clear</button>
```

Comment: It won’t be very accurate if you rely on the timeout function being called exactly every second.  Your best bet is to use the timeout to update the display and use a couple of date objects to accurately track the elapsed time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding milliseconds to your existing code is fairly straight forward. You only need to follow the basic pattern you have established. The only real difference is that you're measuring by 1000 instead of by 60.

What changed:

- Added new var `milli`
- Changed the "frequency" of `timer` to 10 milliseconds (1 millisecond seemed a bit of an overkill)
- When the `Add` function executes we add 10 milliseconds to `milli`
- Added the milliseconds to the end of your current display

### Update

What changed:

- Set `t` to `null` in the "stop" button `onclick` function.
- Changed the `onclick` of the start button to a function rather than pointing it at `timer`. Now we can check `t` and if it does not have a value we run the timer. This stops additional clicks on the start button from running more timers so we don't get "extra" calls to `add`.
- Added ".000" for the milliseconds in the `time` element (I missed this in my first version).
- Added the default ".000" to the displayed value in the "clear" function (I missed this in my first version).
- Added `milli = 0;` in the clear function (I missed this in my first version).

```js
var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0],
    start = document.getElementById('start'),
    stop = document.getElementById('stop'),
    clear = document.getElementById('clear'),
    milli = 0, seconds = 0, minutes = 0, hours = 0,
    t;

function add() {
    milli += 10;
    if (milli >= 1000) {
        milli = 0;
        seconds++;
        if (seconds >= 60) {
            seconds = 0;
            minutes++;
            if (minutes >= 60) {
                minutes = 0;
                hours++;
            }
        }
    }
    
    h1.textContent = (hours ? (hours > 9 ? hours : "0" + hours) : "00") + ":" + (minutes ? (minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes) : "00") + ":" + (seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds) + "." + (milli > 90 ? milli : "0" + milli);

    timer();
}
function timer() {
    t = setTimeout(add, 10);
}
timer();


/* Start button */
start.onclick = function() {
    if(!t) timer();
}

/* Stop button */
stop.onclick = function() {
    clearTimeout(t);
    t = null;
}

/* Clear button */
clear.onclick = function() {
    h1.textContent = "00:00:00.000";
    milli = 0; seconds = 0; minutes = 0; hours = 0;
}
```

```html
<h1><time>00:00:00.000</time></h1>
<button id="start">start</button>
<button id="stop">stop</button>
<button id="clear">clear</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for this, and thank you for the run-through of what changed. It helped me learn. I was on the verge of changing everything and starting from another direction.

Comment: You're welcome. I encourage you to change it all ... all the time ... while you're learning. It's by pushing all the buttons that we learn what they do. There are many and better ways of doing this but I showed you what you asked because you would best understand the answer in terms of what you've already done.

Comment: Yes thanks, I understood everything up to the issue I had. I would have happily started again but at the moment I am happy with my process. It is good that I can carry on with this branch. One other thing, if you woudn't mind. I have been trying to get the add function to  only start when the start button is clicked by editing the if statement but I cant figure it out.

Comment: @JEDBOYLE I have updated the code as you requested. I also cleaned up a few things I missed in my first version.

Comment: Thanks again. This was a pre-test for a job interview, but unfortunately, I didn't get the position. Another addition to my portfolio though.